# Display only the current page number and another numbered page in pagination

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages

I need some help with pagination.

The pagination should only display the current page and another numbered page, like so:

```
<< | 2 | …3 | >>
```

At the moment, it shows all page numbers:

```
<< | 1 | 2 | 3 | …3 | >>
```

Any ideas how to change this?

This is the code:

```
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add');
/**
 * Add prev and next links to a numbered link list
 */
function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $pages, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if ( ! $args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number' )
        return $args; # exit early


    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; # keep numbering for the main part
    if ( ! $more )
        return $args; # exit early

    if( $page - 1 ) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page($page-1) . $args['link_before']
                        . $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after']
                        . '</a>';

    if ( $page < $numpages ) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($page+1) . $args['link_before']
                       . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] 
                       . '</a>' . $args['after'];

    $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($numpages) . $args['link_before']
                   .'...&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $numpages
                   . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
                   . $args['after'];
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: nobody here who can help me with this small problem? I'm ready for it to donate something.